# FB Local Payment error: "Can't parse open graph object. Property price doesn't exist for item"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, payment

I am try set up payment for the FB application for with the static-priced products;
On the Javascript side, I do:

```
   function callOrderUp()
   {
   alert("GO!1");
    FB.ui({
      method : 'pay',
      action: 'purchaseitem',
      display: 'popup',
      product : "https://www.manyfbgames.com/ninetofive/products/product1.html",
      quantity : 1
    },
   function(response) 
  {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    }

  );

  }
```

The contents of product files are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head prefix=
    "og: http://ogp.me/ns# 
     fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
     product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    <meta property="og:type"                   content="og:product" />
    <meta property="og:title"                  content="Test 1" />
    <meta property="og:plural_title"           content="Test 2" />
    <meta property="og:image"                  content="http://manyfbgames.com/ninetofive/products/product1.png" />
    <meta property="og:description"            content="Friend Smash Coins to purchase upgrades and items!" />
    <meta property="og:url"                    content="https://www.manyfbgames.com/ninetofive/products/product1.html" />
    <meta property="product:price:amount"      content="2"/>
    <meta property="product:price:currency"    content="USD"/>
  </head>
</html>
```

For some reason, I always get this error:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 1383051
API Error Description: Can't parse open graph object. Property price doesn't exist for item 218298155037105
```

But I am sure that price to the product data is correct, and I can see that price is set! What else might be causing this?

Comment: Javascript you mean...

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, changed "JAVA" to Javascript, did not trigger that those are a bit different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `og:url` tag pointing to a different URL - this redirects Facebook to that URL, which is not in your control and may not have the correct tags for your product

the `og:url` tag should point to the canonical URL for your object, probably the same URL you're rendering the tags from in most cases

Comment: I did try changing it to: "http://manyfbgames.com/ninetofive/products/product1.html", and also "http://manyfbgames.com/ninetofive/products/index.php" - that is where script is being called from, but result is the same

Comment: Your answer was correct. The only thing I needed to do on top of that, is to refresh the page info inside FB cache using Debug Tools which FB provides.

Comment: If you hit the URL in the debug tool even once, it seems to force clear the cache.  I've gotten this problem on several of my products, and using this cleared it.  I think I got them from having the wrong URL in there at one point, and then it got cached.